# Почему форматирование и вывод даты не работает в switch/case?

Tags: java, строки, дата

Есть вполне рабочий код, который выводит дату из того, что ввел пользователь.

```
        String dateString = scan.nextLine();
    String expectedPattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(expectedPattern);
    try {
        Date date = formatter.parse(dateString);
        System.out.println(dateString);
        System.out.println(date);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Но я не могу понять, почему, когда я записываю этот код внутрь case

```
int choice = scan.nextInt();
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
```

То он перестает работать и выдает ошибку `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""`. То, что мне нужно - это чтобы при выбора определенного case, юзер смог ввести дату, которая записывается потом в массив. Может это можно сделать каким нибудь другим способом?

Comment: У вас дата передается пустая. Воспользуйтесь дебагером и вы сразу увидите, почему dateString пустая возвращается вам

Comment: @AndrewBystrov Но ведь просто так она работает, если в case не вставлять. Не могли ли бы вы объяснить подробнее?

Comment: Это не возможно по тем кускам, которые Вы предоставили. Но скорей всего после int choice = scan.nextInt(); курсор сканера стоит на конце строки и dateString = scan.nextLine(); читает пустую строку. Это только предположение. Сканером никогда не пользовался. не знаю точно как он работает.